# How to play beep once a second Cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

My countdown gets updated every second using my `InGameTime` value that is updated every frame.

This works great visually because I can just round the game time to the nearest int.

...But how do I get my app to play a beep after each second?

Below is my code:

```
-(void) setTimer:(ccTime) delta{

    int timeInSeconds = (int)appDelegate.InGameTime;//Game time E.G: 8.2332432
    /*

            Stuff is here to display the tempTime

    */


    //The below effect plays the sound every frame, 
    //is there an equation that I can apply to appDelegate.InGameTime 
    //that will play it once a second?

    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"tick.mp3"];

}
```

Comment: Just see you whether you can use NSTimer i have done it one of my application using the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(void) setTimer:(ccTime) delta{

    static float timeSinceLastTick = 0.f;

    int timeInSeconds = (int)appDelegate.InGameTime;//Game time E.G: 8.2332432
    /*

        Stuff is here to display the tempTime

    */

    // if your delta is small and relatively constant, this 
    // should be real close to what you want.
    // other ways exist

    timeSinceLastTick += delta;
    if (timeSinceLastTick > 1.0f) {
       timeSinceLastTick=0.f;
       [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"tick.mp3"];
    }

}
```

Comment: Note that though this does trigger once per second, it also may not be correctly synced with the in game time depending on the time this method is scheduled and run for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do this is to keep track of the amount of time in between method calls and relate it to InGameTime.

e.g.

```
- (void)setTimer:(ccTime) delta
{

    int timeInSeconds = (int)appDelegate.InGameTime;//Game time E.G: 8.2332432
    /*

        Stuff is here to display the tempTime

    */


    //The below effect plays the sound every frame, 
    //is there an equation that I can apply to appDelegate.InGameTime 
    //that will play it once a second?

    // beepTime is a float instance variable at first initialized to appDelegate.InGameTime - floor(appDelegate.InGameTime)
    beepTime += delta;

    if (beepTime >= 1.0f) // where 1.0f is the frequency of the beep
    {
        [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"tick.mp3"];
        beepTime = appDelegate.InGameTime - floor(appDelegate.InGameTime); // should return a decimal from 0.0f to 1.0f
    }
}
```

I believe that should work. Let me know.

Comment: By the way, it might not be the most efficient or consistent method. Perhaps someone else can either second my suggestion or offer another.

Comment: Thanks XenElement, I went with YvesLeBorg because it was a slightly simpler solution, but wanted to give you credit as it was the same idea.

Comment: I just want to point out that I did consider the same solution as Yves and rejected it due to the fact that, though it does tick once per second, it also may not be synced correctly with the game time label as the function might not be called right at a whole second. My solution accounts for this, which is the reason for the extra complication.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use schedule method?

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_c_c_node.html#a7e0c230d398bba56d690e025544cb745

You just specify the interval and then put the code to be triggered inside the block

```
//call startBeep function every 1 second
[self schedule:@selector(startBeep:) interval:1.0f];


- (void)startBeep:(ccTime) delta
{
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"tick.mp3"];
}
```